# python - Importing a specific file from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to import only a specific file from Amazon S3 into Google Cloud Services.

In the [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-manage-transfer-program), the procedure mentioned imports all the files from the Amazon source bucket.

```
def main(description, project_id, day, month, year, hours, minutes,
     source_bucket, access_key, secret_access_key, sink_bucket):
"""Create a one-off transfer from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage."""
storagetransfer = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storagetransfer', 'v1')

# Edit this template with desired parameters.
# Specify times below using US Pacific Time Zone.
transfer_job = {
    'description': description,
    'status': 'ENABLED',
    'projectId': project_id,
    'schedule': {
        'scheduleStartDate': {
            'day': day,
            'month': month,
            'year': year
        },
        'scheduleEndDate': {
            'day': day,
            'month': month,
            'year': year
        },
        'startTimeOfDay': {
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes
        }
    },
    'transferSpec': {
        'awsS3DataSource': {
            'bucketName': source_bucket,
            'awsAccessKey': {
                'accessKeyId': access_key,
                'secretAccessKey': secret_access_key
            }
        },
        'gcsDataSink': {
            'bucketName': sink_bucket
        }
    }
}

result = storagetransfer.transferJobs().create(body=transfer_job).execute()
print('Returned transferJob: {}'.format(
    json.dumps(result, indent=4)))
```

On researching a bit further, I came across [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/TransferSpec#ObjectConditions.FIELDS.include_prefixes) which suggests the usage of include_prefixes to specify a certain file.

My question is, how do I integrate the include_prefixes in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but did you try something like the following?

```
'transferSpec': {
    'objectConditions': {
       'includePrefixes': [
           'folder1/folder2/file.png'
        ]            
    },
    'awsS3DataSource': {
        'bucketName': source_bucket,
        'awsAccessKey': {
            'accessKeyId': access_key,
            'secretAccessKey': secret_access_key
        }
    },
    'gcsDataSink': {
        'bucketName': sink_bucket
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it returns an error stating object_conditions was not recognized.